# Change value in JavaScript already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onload

At the top of my index.php file I have a Pullout Panel that uses this:

```
        $(document).ready(function($){
          $('#pocp1').pullOutContentPanel({
            pocp_scrollbars : true,
            pocp_showonload: false, // Modify to true onlick
            pocp_pg_overlay: false,
            pocp_clickout: true
         });
       });
```

Then in a javascript file I have an onclick function that passes the value of a url to a file and renders the results - like so:

```
$("ol").click(function(){

var pathname =  "ajax=1&store_id="+store_id+"&action=get_nearby_stores&distance="+distance+"&lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&products="+$('#edit-products').val();

$("#pocp_content").load("file1.php?" + pathname)
evt.preventDefault();

});
```

What I need to have happen is when the onclick fire for the ol, I need to change the pocp_showonload from false to true. And I need to have it happen without having the page reload at all. This is for a map with listings in the lower panel that all works just fine and the panel will reload with the data after an onclick is fired and show the data just fine. It's just the changing of this that has me stumped.

Comment: I guess that this is jQuery plugin, you are using so there may be no way in doing this if it doesn't support such an operation. If you know the name of the plugin you could check it's API for this, if you haven't yet done so.

Comment: Nowadays you can go full CSS3, and just use JS to toggle classes on and off.

Comment: Thanks for the input @lukasz1985. Can I write some sort of if/else statement for the jquery code at the top of the index.php file? Or move it to the js file and then convert it?

Comment: Yes you can. The actuall dropdown initialization is done after the whole html document is loaded, so if you put a variable in script somewhere, you will most certainly have access to that variable    $(document).ready(function($){  ... from here... }); So you can put  $('#pocp1').pullOutContentPanel({
            pocp_scrollbars : true,
            pocp_showonload: false, // Modify to true onlick
            pocp_pg_overlay: false,
            pocp_clickout: true
         }); inside a conditional statement.

Comment: @lukasz1985 - I tried to do a simple if/else statement, but I guess I was missing the extra variable. Would you mind posting an example please? What I have tried already flat out didn't work.

Comment: I mean something like this: http://pastebin.com/0weiQV4x

Comment: @lukasz1985 - I see, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried setting var someValue = 10; in the onclick function as well as adding <script>var someValue = 10;</script> to the php after is returns the panel refresh. Neither of them work

Comment: @MrTechie  the API for plugin should expose methods to open/close panel...look for docs link in js file if you don't already know ehere it came from

Comment: @charlietfl - this is where it came from http://demos.pixelworkshop.fr/?theme=PullOutContentPanel

Comment: seems no public docs since is paid plugin....look through docs you have that came with it

Comment: That doesn't seem to help me either :( http://test.theslickfeed.com/po/Documentation/#!/javascript